# Adding secondary y-axis for histogram using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

```
set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(x = c(sample(1:500, 800, replace = T)),
       id = rep(1:5, each = 160))

ggplot(df, aes(x)) + geom_histogram() + facet_wrap(~id)
```

[image]

Is there a way for each id, I can draw a secondary y-axis for all x > 300 with the bars and axis coloured in red 
[image]

Comment: Can you clarify your desired result a bit? Do you mean plotting `x<300, x>300` as separate groups? Are you wanting to just duplicate the existing y-axis, but in red? A simple sketch might help.

Comment: I have  tried to add a plot to show what the results should look like